# Why did I get a NullPointerException when I did not use setter in main method?

Tags: java, oop, nullpointerexception

I have a question about using getters and setters, and null pointer exception.

I basically called a simple function, `getSlope()` on a `Line` object, `l`, in my program which has `Line` and `Point` classes.

When I called `l.getSlope()` with 
`Point p1 = new Point(0.0, 3.0);`
`Point p2 = new Point(5.0, 5.0);`
`Line l = new Line(p1, p2);`, it gave me a null pointer exception.

However, when I called `l.getSlope()` with 
`Line l = new Line();`
`l.setP1(0.0, 3.0);`
`l.setP2(5.0, 5.0);`, it DID NOT give me a null pointer exception.

Why is this? Thank you for your help. The code for `Point` and `Line` classes are posted below for your information.

`Point`:

```
public class Point {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Point() {
        this.x = 0.0;
        this.y = 0.0;
    }
    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public double getX() {
        return this.x;
    }
    public double getY() {
        return this.y;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point p = new Point(1.5, 3);
            System.out.println(p.toString());
    }
}
```

`Line`:

```
public class Line {
    private Point p1;
    private Point p2;

    public Line() {
        p1 = new Point(0,0);
        p2 = new Point(0,0);
    }

    public Line(Point p1, Point p2) {
        p1 = new Point(p1.getX(), p1.getY());
        p2 = new Point(p2.getX(), p2.getY());
    }
    public Point getP1() {
        return this.p1;
    }
    public Point getP2() {
        return this.p2;
    }
    public void setP1(double x, double y) {
        this.p1 = new Point (x, y);
    }
    public void setP2(double x, double y) {
        this.p2 = new Point(x, y);
    }
    public double getSlope() {
        return ((p2.getY() - p1.getY()) / (p2.getX() - p1.getX()));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
//      Point p1 = new Point(0.0, 3.0);
//      Point p2 = new Point(5.0, 5.0);
//      Line l = new Line(p1, p2);
//      System.out.println(l.getSlope()); // These 4 lines produced errors
        Line l = new Line();
        l.setP1(0.0, 3.0);
        l.setP2(5.0, 5.0);
        System.out.println(l.getSlope());  // These 4 lines worked!
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `Line` constructor doesn't set the correct `p1` and `p2` variables.  Instead of this: `p1 = new Point(p1.getX(), p1.getY());` do this: `this.p1 = new Point(p1.getX(), p1.getY());`.  Without the `this.p1` qualifier, you're just reassigning a value to the `p1` parameter that's being passed into the constructor, which is immediately discarded when the constructor completes.

Comment: Hi Jordan, thank you for your contribution. Just to make sure, are you suggesting me to do `this.p1 = new Point(p1.getX(), p1.getY());` in my `main` class, or in my `Line` class? However, before that, I don't get how I can use `p1.getX()` to define `this.p1` since I wouldn't be trying to define `p1` if its x and y were already known - could you please explain?

Comment: See my answer for a more detailed explanation.  If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I'll put this in an actual answer, so I have more room to work with.

The issue here is your `Line` constructor.  You're running into something called "variable shadowing".

```
public Line(Point p1, Point p2) {
    p1 = new Point(p1.getX(), p1.getY());
    p2 = new Point(p2.getX(), p2.getY());
}
```

You pass variables into that constructor named `p1` and `p2`:

```
public Line(Point p1, Point p2) // Here are p1 and p2 being passed into the constructor
```

Now you *also* have a `p1` and `p2` defined at the class level, like so:

```
private Point p1;
private Point p2;
```

What you want to do is create new Points based on the `p1` and `p2` being passed into the constructor, and store those new Points in these class-level variables.

But since the constructor has local variables with the same name as the class-level variables, the local variables take precedence, and "hide" the class-level variables.  This is known as "shadowing".

So in the constructor, when you want to access those class-level variables, you have to reference them as `this.p1` and `this.p2`, since `p1` and `p2` refer to the constructor parameters.

```
public Line(Point p1, Point p2) {
    p1; // <-- This is the p1 being passed into the constructor
    this.p1; // <-- This is the class-level variable with the same name
}
```

When you use `this.` to get to the correct variables, the code should look like this:

```
public Line(Point p1, Point p2) {
    this.p1 = new Point(p1.getX(), p1.getY());
    this.p2 = new Point(p2.getX(), p2.getY());
}
```

---

A quick visual reference:

```
private Point p1; // <------------------+
private Point p2; //                    |      
//                                      |
//                +--------------- +    |
//                |                |    |
//                v                |    |
public Line(Point p1, Point p2) {
//                                 |    |
    p1; // <--these are the same---+    |
    this.p1; // <--these are the same---+
}
```